# PHP preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have to do the following with preg_replace in PHP:

`[some text][id]` should be replaced by `<a href='id'>some_text</a>` where `id` is an integer

Tried the following, unfortunately didn't work as expected:

```
preg_replace("/\[[^)]\]\[[0-9]+\]/","<a href='$2'>$1</a>",$string);
```

Also, an example `[some text]][id]` with extra bracket may be considered, where the last bracket should be taken.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, edited. However, either first part, and second part of function doesn't work

Comment: You need to capture what you want to replace to get value into your placeholders.

Comment: If you know the solution, could you please add it in `Answer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
$string = '[some text][117]';
$s = preg_replace("/\[([^\]]+)\]\[([0-9]+)\]/","<a href='$2'>$1</a>",$string);
var_dump($s);
```

First - to use `$1` (or `$2`) you need to capture pattern in brackets `()`.

Second mistake - you're trying to find `^)`, but you don't have `)` in your text. So I replaced `)` to `]`.

**Update** for an extra `]`:

```
$s = preg_replace("/\[([^\]]+)(\]?)\]\[([0-9]+)\]/","<a href='$3'>$1$2</a>",$string);
```

Not sure what you need to do with this founded `]`, so I added it to a link text.

In case of a lot of `]]]` you can use:

```
$s = preg_replace("/\[([^\]]+)(\]*)\]\[([0-9]+)\]/","<a href='$3'>$1$2</a>",$string);
```

Comment: Yeah, I see my mistakes. Thanks!

Comment: Why it doesn't work when I add `htmlspecialchars($string)` as third parameter? For other `preg_replace` functions it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
\[(\D+)\]\[(\d+)\]
```

\D - Any non-digit
\d - Any digit

Test it here: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/k4X